# CEF 3 Disable WebRTC - Ip leaks

Tags: webrtc, chromium-embedded, cefglue

Can we disable WebRTC in CEF 3 ?

I`m referring specifically to JavaScript access to local ips.
Chrome seems to have settings like chrome.privacy.network.webRTCMultipleRoutesEnabled that help - but these do not seem to exist in CEF.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and ended up rebuilding CEF and Chrome without WebRTC support. Here is steps, which I use:

1. Download *automate-git.py* script in c:/code/automate folder from here: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/raw/master/tools/automate/automate-git.py
2. Create batch with following content and run it:

   SET GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015

   python c:/code/automate/automate-git.py --verbose-build --download-dir=C:/code/chromium_git --branch=[REPLACE WITH CURRENT BRANCH] --minimal-distrib --no-debug-build --force-build

   pause
3. Set *enable_webrtc* to 0 inside C:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\build\common.gypi file.
4. Run batch again.

And maybe there there is easier way, for example, using `CefRequestContext::SetPreference`.